# Positive real number $t$ such that $t^2 = at + b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For a positive real number $t$, 
$$t^2 = at + b,$$
where $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers

Then for what values of $x$ and $y$ $t^3$ cannot be represented in the form $xt + y$ where $x \le 16$ and $y < x$ for individual values of $x$ where $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers.

---

**My Attempt at the question:**

1. First I tried to randomly assign values to $a$ and $b$ in order to get the value of $t$ using the Quadratic formula and figure out a pattern in the expression if any. It didn't help me.
2. I tried to do this question by contradiction, assuming that $t^3 = xt + y$ for different values of x and y Which didn't help me either.

Comment: Let me change the question a little bit.

Comment: I fixed the formatting. However, I left your wording the same because I do not understand the question. "for individuals values of $x$"? The quantifiers on $x, y, a, b,$ and $t$ are unclear.

Comment: As in for example x=4, then y = {1,2,3}. Sort of like Euclid's division lemma

Comment: I hope it's clear now

Answer (score 1):

$t^3 = t(at+b) = at^2+bt = a(at+b)+bt = (a^2+b)t+ab$

So you are looking for $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ab=1, a^2+b = 4$, which has no solution.

Comment: After at^2 + bt, you write it that it is equal to a(at+b) + bt. But a(at+b) + bt = a^2*t + bt + ab which is not equal to (at^2+bt).

Comment: I have substituted $t^2$ with $at+b$ in that step.

Comment: Oh... Didn't notice. My bad. And please do see the change in  the question and answer accordingly.

Comment: As I understand, this is a question from KVPY 2016 held yesterday. If so, why dont you just provide the same options they gave (4t+3, 10t+5, 6t+5, 10t+3). Otherwise it becomes too open-ended.

Comment: But I wanted it to be open ended. So that we may arrive at a generalization or observe a pattern